# Time Step in PhysX

Tags: c++, time, game-loop, physx

I'm trying to define a time step for the physics simulation in a PhysX application, such that the physics will run at the same speed on all machines. I wish for the physics to update at 60FPS, so each update should have a delta time of 1/60th of a second.

My application must use GLUT. Currently, my loop is set up as follows.

Idle Function:

```
void GLUTGame::Idle()
{
    newElapsedTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    deltaTime = newElapsedTime - lastElapsedTime;
    lastElapsedTime = newElapsedTime;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

The frame rate does not really matter in this case - it's only the speed at which my physics update that actually matters.

My render function contains the following:

```
void GLUTGame::Render()
{
    // Rendering Code

    simTimer += deltaTime;

    if (simTimer > m_fps)
    {
        m_scene->UpdatePhys(m_fps);
        simTimer = 0;
    }
}
```

Where:

```
Fl32 m_fps = 1.f/60.f
```

However, this results in some very slow updates, due to the fact that deltaTime appears to equal 0 on most loops (which shouldn't actually be possible...) I've tried moving my deltaTime calculations to the bottom of my rendering function, as I thought that maybe the idle callback was called too often, but this did not solve the issue. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [OpenGL website](http://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node70.html), we find that `glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)` returns the number of passed milliseconds as an **int**. So, if you call your `void GLUTGame::Idle()` method about 2000 times per second, then the time passed after one such call is about 1000 * 1/2000 = 0.5 ms. Thus more than 2000 calls per second to void `GLUTGame::Idle()` results in `glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME)` returning **0** due to integer rounding.

Comment: Accepting this answer since it lead me to a solution. Due to glutGet not being accurate enough, I've used `clock()` and `clock_t` from `time.h` instead, which appears to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you're adding very small numbers to larger ones and you get rounding errors. 
Try this:

```
void GLUTGame::Idle()
{
  newElapsedTime = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
  timeDelta = newElapsedTime - lastElapsedTime;
  if (timeDelta <  m_fps) return;
  lastElapsedTime = newElapsedTime;

  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

You can do something similar in the other method if you want to.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to make any difference. `newElapstedTime`, `deltaTime` and `lastElapsedTime` are all doubles. Even though `glutGet` returns milliseconds as an `int` I see no reason why there should be any issues with accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now anything about GLUT or PhysX, but here's how to have something execute at the same rate (using integers) no matter how fast the game runs:

```
if (currentTime - lastUpdateTime > msPerUpdate)
{
    DWORD msPassed = currentTime - lastUpdateTime;
    int updatesPassed = msPassed / msPerUpdate;
    for (int i=0; i<updatesPassed; i++)
        UpdatePhysX(); //or whatever function you use
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime - msPassed + (updatesPassed * msPerUpdate);
}
```

Where `currentTime` is updated to `timeGetTime` every run through the game loop, `lastUpdateTime` is the last time PhysX updated, and `msPerUpdate` is the amount of milliseconds you assign to each update  - 16 or 17 ms for 60fps

If you want to support floating-point update factors (which is recommended for a physics application), then define `float timeMultiplier` and update it every frame like so: `timeMultiplier = (float)frameRate / desiredFrameRate;` - where `frameRate` is self-explanatory and `desiredFramerate` is 60.0f if you want the physics updating at 60 fps.  To do this, you have to update `UpdatePhysX` as taking a `float` parameter that it multiplies all update factors by.